# How can I analyze Python code to identify problematic areas?

Tags: python, static-analysis, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a large source repository split across multiple projects. I would like to produce a report about the health of the source code, identifying problem areas that need to be addressed.

Specifically, I'd like to call out routines with a high cyclomatic complexity, identify repetition, and perhaps run some lint-like static analysis to spot suspicious (and thus likely erroneous) constructs.

How might I go about constructing such a report?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For measuring cyclomatic complexity, there's a nice tool available at [traceback.org](http://www.traceback.org/2008/03/31/measuring-cyclomatic-complexity-of-python-code/).  The page also gives a good overview of how to interpret the results.

+1 for [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint).  It is great at verifying adherence to coding standards (be it [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) or your own organization's variant), which can in the end help to reduce cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: traceback.org is broken link

Comment: Pylint is great, but slow.  We use as a pre-push hook, but use flake8 and a bunch of plugins for regular checks and pre-commit hook.   I'd actually recommend `https://flakehell.readthedocs.io/config.html` these days though, as it's execution model is much more robust and configurable.

Answer (score 29):

For cyclomatic complexity you can use `radon`: https://github.com/rubik/radon

(Use `pip` to install it: `pip install radon`)

Additionally it also has these features:

- raw metrics (these include SLOC, comment lines, blank lines, &c.)
- Halstead metrics (all of them)
- Maintainability Index (the one used in Visual Studio)

Comment: What's the switch to get Halstead metrics?

Comment: @qarma If I understand the docs, I don't think you can use the command line. You have to use the Python API.

Answer (score 18):

For static analysis there is [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) and [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/). Personally I use pylint as it seems to be more comprehensive than pychecker.

For cyclomatic complexity you can try [this perl program](http://www.journyx.com/curt/complexity.html), or this [article](http://www.traceback.org/2008/03/31/measuring-cyclomatic-complexity-of-python-code/) which introduces a python program to do the same

Answer (score 11):

Pycana works like charm when you need to understand a new project!

> [PyCAna](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pycana/) (Python Code Analyzer) is
>   a fancy name for a simple code
>   analyzer for python that creates a
>   class diagram after executing your
>   code.

See how it works:
http://pycana.sourceforge.net/

output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [Pydev](http://pydev.org/), you can [integrate pylint](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html) in the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) really easily and get a code report each time you save a modified file.

Answer (score 6):

Use [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8), which provides pep8, pyflakes, and cyclomatic complexity analysis in one tool

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called 
[CloneDigger](http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/) that helps you find similar code snippets.

Comment: It does not work with Python 3 and it never was well maintained.

Answer (score 3):

For checking cyclomatic complexity, there is of course the [**`mccabe`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mccabe/) package.

Installation:

```
$ pip install --upgrade mccabe
```

Usage:

```
$ python -m mccabe --min=6 path/to/myfile.py
```

Note the threshold of 6 above. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365185/832230), scores >5 probably should be simplified.

Sample output with `--min=3`:

```
68:1: 'Fetcher.fetch' 3
48:1: 'Fetcher._read_dom_tag' 3
103:1: 'main' 3
```

It can optionally also be used via [pylint-mccabe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint-mccabe/) or [pytest-mccabe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-mccabe/), etc.