# How to check syntax(no compilation) error in python code

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, static-code-analysis

i have a python file and want to check syntax error without compiling. I know about 'compileall', 'py_compile' but these all compile the code.

Comment: What are you using? IDE? Text editor? If you open the file in IDLE, you can use Run > Check Module

Comment: I am using vi editor (linux) to write and run the file. I was lloking for command line option for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/100298/1025391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you'll need some static code analysis. There are several tools that can do so with Python:

- [Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/)
- [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes)

Personally, I use Pylint. It is rather strict but with some minimal configuration you'll get quickly some useful feedback. It can be installed using pip:

```
pip install pylint
pylint <my_module>.py
```

There are some options to scan whole folders. Have a look at http://docs.pylint.org/run.html